# Counting Products ordered more than once

Tags: mysql

I need to get the count of a product that was ordered more than once and ordered only once by customers. I may be looking at this the wrong way, please forgive me if the sql looks stupid or something.

```
SELECT ActualOrder.Sku,
COUNT(DISTINCT Email) AS UniqueCustomer,
COUNT(DISTINCT OrderNumber) AS NumOrders,
COUNT(Reordered.Sku) AS NumReordered,
COUNT(OrderedOnce.Sku) AS NumOrderedOnce
FROM ActualOrder
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Sku FROM ActualOrder GROUP BY Email HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT OrderNumber) > 1) AS Reordered ON ActualOrder.Sku = Reordered.Sku
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Sku FROM ActualOrder GROUP BY Email HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT OrderNumber) = 1) AS OrderedOnce ON ActualOrder.Sku = OrderedOnce.Sku
GROUP BY ActualOrder.Sku
```

---

From John Woo's idea of getting the count from the subquery, I came up with this code, which actually does work, but a bit nested. Maybe you guys can help me make this more efficient or at least shorter. Thanks again for all the help!

```
SELECT ActualOrder.Sku,
COUNT(DISTINCT Email) AS UniqueCustomer,
COUNT(DISTINCT OrderNumber) AS NumOrders,
NumReordered,
NumOrderedOnce
FROM ActualOrder
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Sku, SUM(IF(NumCustomerOrders>1,1,0)) AS NumReordered, SUM(IF(NumCustomerOrders=1,1,0)) AS NumOrderedOnce
    FROM (SELECT Sku, Email, COUNT(DISTINCT OrderNumber) AS NumCustomerOrders
        FROM ActualOrder GROUP BY Sku, Email)
    AS Orders GROUP BY Sku) AS OrderCount ON ActualOrder.Sku = OrderCount.Sku
GROUP BY ActualOrder.Sku
```

Answer (score 2):

you can count the total number of orders on the `subquery`

```
SELECT  ActualOrder.Sku,
        Reordered.NumReordered,
        OrderedOnce.NumOrderedOnce
        COUNT(DISTINCT Email) AS UniqueCustomer,
        COUNT(DISTINCT OrderNumber) AS NumOrders
FROM ActualOrder
        LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT Sku, COUNT(*) NumReordered
            FROM ActualOrder 
            GROUP BY Email 
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
        ) AS Reordered ON ActualOrder.Sku = Reordered.Sku
        LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT Sku, COUNT(*) NumOrderedOnce
            FROM ActualOrder 
            GROUP BY Email 
            HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
        ) AS OrderedOnce ON ActualOrder.Sku = OrderedOnce.Sku
GROUP BY    ActualOrder.Sku,
            Reordered.NumReordered,
            OrderedOnce.NumOrderedOnce
```

Comment: Hi John. I can't seem to make your code work, but I was able to work something out of your idea of getting the count from the subquery. Although, it is a bit nested. I'll post the code on my question. Maybe you guys can come up with a more efficient one.

Comment: @MarcelLainez in my own opinion, your current query works great because you can't aggregate the aggregated column on the same query, for example, `SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT OrderNumber))`

Comment: Yes, I was trying that out initially. Hehe. Thanks again!